# Awk print next after matched condition?

Tags: awk

When using the command: `awk 'f&&!--f;{if(length($1)>8){f=1}}' awk.write` I can print line after the matched line.

I know the usage of `flags` but have no idea what `&&!--f` really does?

```
this line 1 no un1x
this lines 22 0
butbutbut this 33 22 has unix
but not 1
THIS is not
butbutbut ffff
second line
```

Comment: Code looks unnecessarily complicated (obfuscation intended?). It's the same as `awk 'f; {f = length($1) > 8}' awk.write`, that is "print the line if the first field of the previous line is more than 8 chars long".  Unless you haven't given us all the lines?

Comment: @xhienne: it's a special case of `f&&!--f{print_etc} cond{f=N}` which operates on the Nth line after the condition; for N=1 your simplification works but not N>1. OTOH `NR==x{print_etc} cond{x=NR+N}` works equally for any N>=1.

Comment: Thank you @dave_thompson_085, that explains things indeed. As for your alternate program, the result would be different if several files are given in input (and replacing `NR` with `FNR` would not be enough).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at `f&&!--f`. Here, both conditions `f` and `!--f` need to evaluate to True, in order to have the default action (print the line) executed. `&&` is the logical `AND`.

A statement in `awk` is true if it evaluates to something other than `0`. So, the first condition is true if `f` is not `0`.

`!--f` means decrease `f` by `1` immediately (`f--` also decreases by one, but only a bit later, see [this documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Increment-Ops) for details). And `!` negates the truth value of the previous statement. So, if `f` is `1`, `--f` becomes `0`, a.k.a. False. The `!` makes this True. This is supposed to catch the circumstance if `f` does not equal `1`.

In this simple example, this second test is not strictly necessary, but makes sure `f` is reset to `0`. A shorter version would be:

```
awk 'f&&!--f;length($1)>8{f=1}' awk.write
```

And possibly easier to understand:

```
awk 'f&&{print;f=0};length($1)>8{f=1}' awk.write
```

Comment: excellent but if i use same command can i print line above the matched condition?

Comment: Sure, that is easier. `awk 'length($1)>8{print s};{s=$0}' file`.

Comment: great it works but where in code it tells to print one line before?

Comment: This code says: If condition is matched, print variable `s`. Then, regardless of condition, the current line is stored in `s`. So in effect, `s` is set to the previous line when the condition is checked.

Comment: you said current line but `$0` is a record buffer it contains all the lines ?

Comment: If you are not playing with `RS`, a record and a line are the same.